# There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree. Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, flutter-bottomnavigation

This error occur whenever i click the Google Sign-In button. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5J4a.png). After entering the google sign-in button, it should navigate the user to a bottom navigation bar [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4TX1.png). If the user haven't sign out, the app will save the token and the user will access the bottom navigation bar directly without required google sign in again...How can i solve it?

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>
# Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero)
```

google sign-in page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:liquid_swipe/liquid_swipe.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Authen/Google_SignIn.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/BottomNavigationBar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/globalVariable.dart' as global;
import 'package:custom_clippers/custom_clippers.dart';

import '../OCR/OCR_Page.dart';

class MyliquidSwipe extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyliquidSwipe({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyliquidSwipe> createState() => _MyliquidSwipeState();
}

class _MyliquidSwipeState extends State<MyliquidSwipe>{



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final page = [
      //2rd page
      MaterialApp(home: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 185, 174, 151),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/IntroPage/Tip Ingredient for Health Hint.png',
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              Column(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 3),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Container(
                          child: Text(
                        'Welcome To',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.06,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 172, 152, 129)),
                      ))),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 3),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Recipes Collector',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.08,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 172, 152, 129)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/IntroPage/TIFH.png',
                    ),
                    height: 310,
                    width: 310,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.030,
                ),
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage(
                          'assets/IntroPage/Intro Tag.png',
                        ),
                        // alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('Tip Ingredient for Health Hint',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.048,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.82,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            )),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 196, 192, 182),
                            ),
                          ),
                          The Error happen whenever i click the Google Sign-In Button
                          vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                          onPressed: () =>
                              googleSignIn().whenComplete(() async {
                            FirebaseUser user =
                                await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => BottomNav()));
                            global.retrieveUserData();
                          }),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    child: Image.network(
                                        'http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19635.png',
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 15,
                                ),
                                Text("Let's Start With Google !",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.045,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )))
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        );
      })),
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LiquidSwipe(
        enableLoop: false,
        pages: page,
        slideIconWidget: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_left_sharp,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

bottom navigation bar code

````
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/All%20Recipes/viewpage.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/OCR/OCR_Page.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Profile/Profile.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Recipes%20Collection/RecipeSearch.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Recipes%20Collection/recipe_collection_home.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/BottomNavigationBar.dart';
import 'BuyingList/cartHome.dart';

class BottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNav({super.key});

  @override
  // _BottomNavState createState() => _BottomNavState();
  State<BottomNav> createState() => _BottomNavState();
}

class _BottomNavState extends State<BottomNav> {
  
  int _currentindex = 2;
    List pages = [RecipesViewPage(),RecipeCollectorHome(),OCRPage(),HomeCart(),Profile()];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       home: Scaffold(
          body: pages[_currentindex],
          bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
              style: TabStyle.reactCircle,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
              items: [
                TabItem(icon: Icons.travel_explore, title: 'All'),
                TabItem(icon: Icons.explore, title: 'Collection'),
                TabItem(icon: Icons.edit_note_rounded, title: 'OCR'),
                TabItem(icon: Icons.message, title: 'Grocery'),
                TabItem(icon: Icons.perm_contact_cal, title: 'Profile'),
              ],
              initialActiveIndex: 2, //optional, default as 0
              onTap: (int i) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentindex = i;
                });
              })),
     );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one `FloatingActionButton` in your code, set their `heroTag` attributes to different values(String).

Answer (score 0):

Hero widget heroTag must be a unique tag. if you duplicate it, will throw this error.

Comment: how can i solve it? i had try many method, but still not work...